# How to find the optimal mapping between two sets?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, both of $n$ points $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$. I want to find a bijective function $f:A \rightarrow B$ so that the cost $C$ is minimal. It's defined as the sum of all pair's euclidean distances.

$$C =\sum_{p \in A}{|p - f(p)|}$$

Can this be calculated directly? If not, what is the most efficient way to find it? Please provide the formula or algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a thing is called a minimum weight perfect matching for a bipartite graph.  There is a polynomial time $O(n^3)$ algorithm for this with an interesting history stretching back to Jacobi, often called [the Hungarian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).  Some [lecture notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/matching-notes.pdf) give background in Section 1.2.

Answer (score 6):

This is called a "transportation problem", which is a special case of a network flow problem.  Efficient algorithms are well-known.  The linear programming formulation uses variables $x_{ij} \in [0,1]$ for $i \in A$, $j \in B$.

minimize $\sum_{i,j} |i-j| x_{ij}$ subject to $\sum_i x_{ij} =1$, $\sum_j x_{ij} = 1$, $0 \le x_{ij} \le 1$.